# Как поместить ползунок в конец скролбара при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, css

Есть  div со свойством overflow:scroll. Как сделать так что бы при загрузке страницы скрол перемещался в самый конец?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var block = document.getElementById("block");
      block.scrollTop = block.scrollHeight;
</script>
```

Здесь block - это div в виде объекта, scrollHeight - высота скролла, scrollTop - собственно установка скролла.

Answer (score 2):

Если с использованием jquery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("scrollBlock").animate({ scrollTop: $('scrollBlock').prop("scrollHeight") }, 1000);
});
```

Пример:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("main").animate({ scrollTop: $('main').prop("scrollHeight") }, 1000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main p {
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ddd;
}

main {
  background: #ccc;  
  height: 100%; 
  padding: 1rem;
  
  
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<main>
  <p>
    <span>start</span>
    <span>end</span>
  </p>
</main>
```